# Default Routing Not working in .NET MVC 1 (and 2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

My default routes are very simple, but the page doesn't properly load without fully qualifying the entire route.

Here are the routes I'm using:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Here's the only action in the application in a HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Content("New stuff");
}
```

With these URLs:

```
http://localhost:8081/NewMvc1/
```

I get `The incoming request does not match any route.`

With:

```
http://localhost:8081/NewMvc1/Home
http://localhost:8081/NewMvc1/Home/Index
```

I get a 404 Mvc page that says it tried to handle the request with a static file.

Yet, finally with a 'fully qualified url'

```
http://localhost:8081/NewMvc1/Home/Index/1
```

I get the expected result output from the one and only one action.

```
New Stuff
```

This doesn't seem right at all.  I've also been getting Failed to Execute Action from this same application (not sure if that's related).

I've used Phil Haack's RouteDebugger to get this far, which pointed out that it wasn't matching the URL when the Optional parameters were missing, but did when those parameters were provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `id` from your defaults:

```
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```